# PLSQL not all variables bound

Tags: oracle, plsql, bind-variables

i keep getting the following errror, 'ORA-01008: not all variables bound', im guessign its
all based on my pPostcode param but im not sure. 
I am a beginner the the whole PLSQL secne and any help would be greatly apriciated

here is my procedure:

```
 procedure all_customer_postcode(pPostcode in carer.postcode%type
                                ,pReport out SYS_REFCURSOR) is
  begin
    open pReport for
      select c.id, c.forename, c.surname,c.address_1,c.address_2,
             c.address_3,c.address_4, c.postcode, c.date_of_birth, cf.id    
        from customer c, customer_friend cf,customer_friend_for cff 
       where c.id = cff.customer_id AND cff.id = cff.customer_friend_id
       AND c.postcode = pPostcode;
  end;
```

Thanks Jon

Comment: How are you calling this procedure?  Because there is no obvious problem with the posted code.

Comment: yeah the procedure is being called, soo would you suggest that its somthing outside of this procedure?  thanks for responding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have amended your procedure slight, as the WHERE clause you published didn't make sense to me...

```
SQL> create or replace procedure all_customer_postcode
  2          (pPostcode in customer.postcode%type
  3                                  ,pReport out SYS_REFCURSOR) is
  4  begin
  5      open pReport for
  6        select c.id
  7               , c.forename
  8               , c.surname
  9               ,c.address_1
 10               ,c.address_2
 11               ,c.postcode
 12               , c.date_of_birth
 13               , cf.id  as cf_id
 14          from customer c
 15              , customer_friend cf
 16              ,customer_friend_for cff
 17         where c.id = cff.customer_id
 18         AND cf.id = cff.customer_friend_id
 19         AND c.postcode = pPostcode;
 20  end;
 21  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Calling it in SQL*Plus with variables works ...

```
SQL> var rc refcursor
SQL> var pc varchar2(8)
SQL> exec :pc := 'ML1 4KJ'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec all_customer_postcode(:pc, :rc)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

        ID FORENAME   SURNAME    ADDRESS_1            ADDRESS_2            POSTCODE DATE_OF_B      CF_ID
---------- ---------- ---------- -------------------- -------------------- -------- --------- ----------
         1 Joe        Chip       1234 Telepath Drive  Milton Lumpky        ML1 4KJ  01-FEB-90         11
         4 Ray        Hollis     777 Telepath Drive   Milton Lumpky        ML1 4KJ  01-SEP-81         44
         5 Pat        Conley     1235 Telepath Drive  Milton Lumpky        ML1 4KJ  01-OCT-91         55

SQL>
```

So, how can we get it to hurl an ORA-1008?  By turning the query into a string and changing the way the parameter is declared...

```
SQL> create or replace procedure all_customer_postcode
  2          (pPostcode in customer.postcode%type
  3                                  ,pReport out SYS_REFCURSOR) is
  4  begin
  5      open pReport for
  6        'select c.id
  7               , c.forename
  8               , c.surname
  9               ,c.address_1
 10               ,c.address_2
 11               ,c.postcode
 12               , c.date_of_birth
 13               , cf.id  as cf_id
 14          from customer c
 15              , customer_friend cf
 16              ,customer_friend_for cff
 17         where c.id = cff.customer_id
 18         AND cf.id = cff.customer_friend_id
 19         AND c.postcode = :pPostcode';
 20  end;
 21  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec all_customer_postcode(:pc, :rc)
BEGIN all_customer_postcode(:pc, :rc); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01008: not all variables bound
ORA-06512: at "APC.ALL_CUSTOMER_POSTCODE", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

so let's fix *that* ...

```
SQL> create or replace procedure all_customer_postcode
  2          (pPostcode in customer.postcode%type
  3                                  ,pReport out SYS_REFCURSOR) is
  4  begin
  5      open pReport for
  6        'select c.id
  7               , c.forename
  8               , c.surname
  9               ,c.address_1
 10               ,c.address_2
 11               ,c.postcode
 12               , c.date_of_birth
 13               , cf.id  as cf_id
 14          from customer c
 15              , customer_friend cf
 16              ,customer_friend_for cff
 17         where c.id = cff.customer_id
 18         AND cf.id = cff.customer_friend_id
 19         AND c.postcode = :pPostcode' using pPostcode;
 20  end;
 21  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec all_customer_postcode(:pc, :rc)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

So I have managed to recreate an ORA-1008; I'm not sure whether it matches your ORA-1008 situation.  Your intuition is right, it is something to do with how the value in `pPostcode` is passed to the query.  It is just that the code you posted actually does it correctly and so doesn't fail.

Comment: Sir i am in your debt, you couldnt have given a more concise awnser 
thank you

Comment: @unknown, in future I suggest you post the exact code that was failing, instead of making us guess :)