# "Not all variables are bound" Error when passing parameters

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm using PL/SQL and I get the "Not all variables are bound" when I execute the sql expression. I'm selecting data by passing values into 3 parameters. Therefore "host variables" do not help me in here.

```
SELECT SomeApi1_Api.Get_Part_No(t.or_no, t.l_no, t.rel_no, t.item_no),
       t.description,
       c.serial_no,
       c.lot_batch_no,
       t.order_no,
       t.line_no,
       t.release_no,
       SomeApi1_Api.Get_State(t.or_no, t.l_no, t.rel_no, t.item_no)
FROM TableView1 c,
     TableView2 t
WHERE c.or_no = t.or_no
  AND c.l_no = t.l_no
  AND c.rel_no = t.rel_no
  AND c.item_no = t.item_no
  AND deliv_no IN (SELECT deliv_no
                   FROM TableView3 a
                   WHERE a.del_no IN (SELECT DISTINCT dele_no
                                      FROM TableView3 cod,
                                           TableView4 cdi
                                      WHERE cod.deliv_no = cdi.deliv_no
                                        AND cdi.i_id = t.i_id
                                        AND cdi.item_id = t.item_id
                                        AND cdi.co = t.co
                                        AND a.or_no = t.or_no
                                        AND a.l_no = l_no
                                        AND a.rel_no = rel_no
                                        AND a.item_no = item_no))
  AND t.i_id = '&A'
  AND t.item_id = '&B'
  AND t.co = '&C'
```

Comment: Can you post your complete code attempt I believe you may have used cursor select

Comment: Check this SO discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176388/plsql-not-all-variables-bound